# DGET with multiple (compound) keys returns #NUM! error

Tags: filter, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query, gs-vlookup

What is the logic of the DGET function with multiple criteria keys?
I have made two small examples to investigate:

**Case 1:** we get a value by Date type key only - it works fine.

[image]

**Case 2:** same data, but we add a String type key. Here we have an error!

[image]

I agree, there are 2 "М000001735" strings in column B ("Инв" field). But there are also 2 keys to get a unique row in this case. What is wrong? Can I use DGET function **for compound keys**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The table should **not** contain any duplicates. If there are duplicates, you should remove that by using the `UNIQUE` or `SORT` function that you can use within the `DGET`. Because if there are multiple matches, `DGET` will return an error. The `DGET` formula returns `#VALUE!` error if the criterion doesn't match. So you should wrap Google Sheets `DGET` formula with an `IFERROR`. Duplicates in the criteria/lookup column are not allowed. This causes `#NUM!` error in `DGET`.

---

if you run: `={{1;2}\{3;4}}`

or run this constellation: `={{1\3};{2\4}}`

you will get the same result which means either of these will work:

```
=DGET(A:C; "Рабочее место"; {{"Инв" \ "Дата"}; {"М000001735" \ DATE(2019; 2; 15)}})
```

---

```
=DGET(A:C; "Рабочее место"; {{"Дата"; "Инв"}; {DATE(2019; 2; 15); "М000001735"}})
```

---

```
=DGET(A:C; "Рабочее место"; {{"Инв"; "М000001735"} \ {"Дата"; DATE(2019; 2; 15)}})
```

[image: 0]

### [demo spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1jYfQOxj2sv7QS5OD9ct3OAYB3IM6AGx2gqZm8VgrLok/edit#gid=1259555414)

**note:** make sure you use Russian Locale in Spreadsheet Settings

### _____________________________________________________________

alternatives to `DGET`:

```
=QUERY(A:C; "select C where A = date '2019-2-15' and B = 'М000001735'"; 0)
```

---

```
=FILTER(C:C; A:A=DATE(2019; 2; 15); B:B="М000001735")
```

---

```
=VLOOKUP(VLOOKUP(DATE(2019; 2; 15); A:B; 2; 0); B:C; 2; 0)
```

---

Comment: Thank you for very good alternatives (especially `FILTER` case). But my question is about DGET syntax and correct understanding. I still have no ideas how to solve my initial task directly.

Comment: No problem - [this one](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1K93X6RehAVe4bOEDPzgekeuj1oxBUYoYsw0QHNQVICs/edit?usp=sharing). In addition, I have noticed, that DGET is sensitive for the criteria order - see **Short!G1** cell with the working formula. But if I append data into A:C to have duplicate keys (see "Long" sheet), the formula still works. Very inevident behavior!

Comment: Sorry, but recommended `=DGET(A1:C; "Рабочее место"; {{"Инв"; "M00001735"}\{"Дата"; DATE(2019; 2; 15)}})` returns #ERROR!

Comment: Great, thank you very much for the demo! The only note is about **E4** cell: this variant does not work... after replacing `DATE(2019; 2; 15)` by `DATE(2018; 10; 19)`. We are very close to understand the reason.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194698/discussion-between---and-player0).

Answer (score 0):

It helps if an [OP](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/256420) explains what they are trying to achieve (as well as what problem they encountered, and where, data sample in text format and so forth).

Please try:

```
=DGET(A$1:C;"Рабочее место";{{"Инв";"M00001735"}\{"Дата";DATE(2019;2;15)}})
```

Your 'default' separator is `;` hence in your case this does not serve to stack arrays horizontally.

Comment: What is "OP"? I have tried your formula and got #VALUE! errror. Then I have used `=DGET(A$1:C;"Рабочее место"; {{"Инв";"Дата"}\{"М000001735";DATE(2019;2;15)}})` and got #VALUE! again. I have replaced back slash with semicolon - same result. But when I placed compound criteria into 4 cells range and inserted range reference into the formula, it works! So, what is the correct syntax without range reference?